# using lappy and elseif command

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply

Using R I have a table, lets say 'locations'

```
head(locations, n=10)
       apillar fender fwheel fdoor compart rdoor rwheel boot
1        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    1
2        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0
3        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0
4        0      1      0     0       0     0      0    0
5        1      0      1     0       0     0      0    0
6        1      0      0     1       0     0      0    0
7        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    0
8        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0
9        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0
10       0      0      0     0       0     1      0    0
```

now i want to create a new variable "cat" which groups the impacts into category locations.
I have been using if, elseif and else command, but I cannot get it to work.
The command is:

```
cat <- lapply(locations, function(x) if (apillar|fender|fwheel == 1)print("front") else if (fdoor|compart|rdoor == 1)print("middle") else if(rwheel|boot ==1)print("rear") else print("NA")
```

such that cat should read rear, middle, middle, middle, front etc

Comment: `elseif` is not an R command. You probably want `else if`.

Comment: What gave you the impression that there is an `elseif` in R and that you could combine logical expressions like this? Read the documentation and study some introductionary materials.

Comment: thank you @Thomas
Aside from that, is it possible to do my achieve my objective using these commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your own code:

```
locations$cat= with(locations, ifelse(apillar|fender|fwheel, "front", ifelse(fdoor|compart|rdoor,"middle",ifelse(rwheel|boot, "rear", "NA"))) )
> locations
   apillar fender fwheel fdoor compart rdoor rwheel boot    cat
1        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    1   rear
2        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0 middle
3        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0 middle
4        0      1      0     0       0     0      0    0  front
5        1      0      1     0       0     0      0    0  front
6        1      0      0     1       0     0      0    0  front
7        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    0     NA
8        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0 middle
9        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0 middle
10       0      0      0     0       0     1      0    0 middle
>
```

Answer (score 1):

When vectors of `TRUE` or `FALSE` statements are involved, I usually prefer not to work with `if` to avoid loops. I find conditional referencing to be more elegant in this case. See below.

```
locations <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"apillar fender fwheel fdoor compart rdoor rwheel boot
1        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    1
2        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0
3        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0
4        0      1      0     0       0     0      0    0
5        1      0      1     0       0     0      0    0
6        1      0      0     1       0     0      0    0
7        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    0
8        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0
9        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0
10       0      0      0     0       0     1      0    0")

locations$cat <- NA

within(locations,{
  cat[apillar|fender|fwheel] <- "front"
  cat[fdoor|compart|rdoor] <- "middle"
  cat[rwheel|boot] <- "rear"
})
```

Result:

```
   apillar fender fwheel fdoor compart rdoor rwheel boot    cat
1        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    1   rear
2        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0 middle
3        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0 middle
4        0      1      0     0       0     0      0    0  front
5        1      0      1     0       0     0      0    0  front
6        1      0      0     1       0     0      0    0 middle
7        0      0      0     0       0     0      0    0   <NA>
8        0      0      0     0       1     0      0    0 middle
9        0      0      0     1       0     0      0    0 middle
10       0      0      0     0       0     1      0    0 middle
```

Cheers!